# Anchoring html framework

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using html/css/javascript as a game UI for a 3D game. I render the page on top of my game. Most game UI's have an anchoring concept (position widgets to Top, Left, Right, Bottom, Center, LeftCenter, RightCenter, TopCenter, BottomCenter). I'm wondering if anyone knows of any existing html/css framework out there that mimics this behavior or if it's fairly easy to do such a thing with css? I'm not all that familiar with css and I've done some searching around this but haven't seen anything that seems like it's a direct anchoring like I was referring to above. It seems like anchoring div's like this would be ideal in my situation.

I'm picturing behavior like anchoring a div to the bottom center and when I add things inside of it the overall div itself always stays centered at the bottom no matter if I resize the window.

Comment: look at css `position: fixed` it basically causes the element to act like a watermark

Comment: So would I have to calculate the pixel position for this then when screen resolutions change? I'm looking at this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed and they have actual pixels. That's something I would have to do manually then in javascript or something? Generally anchoring libraries automatically keep their anchor position. With this is seems centering wouldn't do that.

Comment: You can also do percentages. I.E. width:15%;

Comment: there is a way to do `left: 0;` and `right:0` and it should be centered

Comment: or you could do an exterior div, set `width: 100%`,  and put your centered div inside of it with `margin: auto`

Comment: So that's just centered. Is the idea that to get all the anchors I listed is not as easy as just saying Anchor: TopLeft; in some kind of library? No library out there that handles all of this stuff for me? I'll dig more into fixed and such as well.

Comment: if you want it bottom-left you would do css `bottom: 0; left: 0;` if you wanted top-center you could do css `top:0; left:0; right:0;` (I think you can get where I'm going with that without explaining all the different scenarios)

Comment: I'm almost wondering if a table would be better for this. I mean I can specify each of those cells easily enough. When I was more into web design back in the day tables were the way we did this, but seems people are going crazy if you do that these days, but since it's for this game UI and not a webpage really maybe tables are the way to go to specify these anchor cells. From there I can use divs and such inside that basic template.

Comment: @Seth That's interesting. I would have never guessed specifying 0 for left and right would center, but I see how this is working now. I'll play with that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, its a hidden gem in css... it would have been a lot easer if you just had a freaking `center` flag

Comment: What am I missing here? It's not centered: https://jsfiddle.net/0bw85v5c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Comment as answer:

Look at css `position: fixed` it basically causes the element to act like a watermark

If you want it bottom-left you would do

- `css bottom: 0; left: 0;`

If you wanted top-center you could do

- `css top:0; left:0; right:0;`

(I think you can get where I'm going with that without explaining all the different scenarios)

> left: 0, right: 0 seems to just make the div take up the entire width. Giving a width of 50% doesn't center that div of a width of 50% it seems.

**Response**

try html

```
<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#a {
 position: fixed;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
#b {
 width: 50%;
 margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: left: 0, right: 0 seems to just make the div take up the entire width. Giving a width of 50% doesn't center that div of a width of 50% it seems.

Comment: I'm still contemplating if a table would be easier for this. I would have distinct areas where I could put stuff in. Centering with divs and such always seems a little not exactly what I'm thinking like it should be.

Comment: Tables are old school, but very reliable ;)